# Sine wave amplitude to binary MATLAB lookup table

Tags: digital-logic, matlab, sine

I'm trying to generate a 256 point 8-bit sine lookup table for digital synthesis. I wrote the below MATLAB code for generating the binary numbers from amplitude and copying into a data file. It works but the output is not symmetric as you can see. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me with this?

```
clear all; close all;
fs=40;
amp=1;
t=0:1/fs:2*pi;
sine_w=amp*sin(t);
figure();
plot(t,sine_w);
total_wordlength=8;
scaling=7;
sine_int=round(sine_w.*(2^scaling));
sine_binary=dec2bin(mod((sine_int),2^total_wordlength),total_wordlength);
yy=cellstr(sine_binary);
fid=fopen('sine_value.data','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%8s \n', yy{:});
display('text file for signal finished');
```

Comment: In what way is it not symmetric?

Comment: If you take the latter half of the list, invert it, fold it backwards  it is the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: You can always use an online tool for lookup table generation, for example my one:
https://ppelikan.github.io/drlut/

Answer (score 2):

So I think you missed that dec2bin only works with unsigned numbers.

Here is my version which does a Two's complement conversion after generating a unsigned sine with offset

Note: Syntax like ++ only works with octave... if you use matlab, you need to do something like x=x+1;

```
clear all;
close all;

fig=1;

nos=256;
amp=1;
t=0:(2.*pi)./(nos.-1):(2.*pi);

sine_w=amp.*sin(t);
figure(fig++);
plot(t,sine_w);
grid on;

number_of_bits=8;
ampl_pp = 2.*amp;

lsb = ((2.^number_of_bits)-1)./ampl_pp;
sine_discrete_signed_tmp = (sine_w.*lsb);
sine_discrete_signed = int8(sine_discrete_signed_tmp);
max(sine_discrete_signed_tmp)
min(sine_discrete_signed_tmp)

figure(fig++);
plot(t,sine_discrete_signed);
grid on;

sine_discrete_unsigned_tmp = ((1.+sine_w).*lsb);
sine_discrete_unsigned = uint8(sine_discrete_unsigned_tmp);
max(sine_discrete_unsigned)
min(sine_discrete_unsigned)

figure(fig++);
plot(t,sine_discrete_unsigned);
grid on;

length = size(sine_discrete_unsigned,2);
sine_unsigned_2thcompl = zeros(1,length);
for(n=1:1:length)
  if(0 <= sine_discrete_signed(:,n))
    sine_unsigned_2thcompl(:,n) = sine_discrete_unsigned(:,n) .- (2^(number_of_bits.-1));
  else
    sine_unsigned_2thcompl(:,n) = (2^(number_of_bits.-1)) .+ sine_discrete_unsigned(:,n);
  endif  
endfor
max(sine_unsigned_2thcompl)
min(sine_unsigned_2thcompl)

figure(fig++);
plot(t,sine_unsigned_2thcompl);
grid on;

yy=(dec2bin(sine_unsigned_2thcompl));

fid=fopen('sine_value.data','wt');
for(n=1:1:size(yy,1))
  fprintf(fid, '%s \n', yy(n,:));
endfor
fclose(fid);
display('text file for signal finished');
```

[image: result in signed integers twos complement]

with only 6 Bits and a stairplot the discrete steps are clearly visible

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are bunch of things happening here.

1. `dec2bin` and `bin2dec` aren't great with signed integers. It may be better to manage the 2's complement manually
2. Your sine wave includes +128 which is out of bounds. You either need to manually clip this to 127 or scale the whole sine wave by 127/128 so it's symmetric and  going from -127 to + 127
3. Your table is not 256 points long. If you create the argument for the sine, make sure to EXCLUDE 2*pi (since it's duplicates what's already at 0). That's probably the main reason for your asymmetry in your data

Here is a script that produces C code with a max amplitude of 127

```
%% create an 8 bit sine table

% create a 256 sine table EXCLUDING 2*pi, cap at 127 and round
n = 256;
sineTable = round(127*sin(2*pi*(0:n-1)'./n));

% create 2's complement
sineTable(sineTable < 0) = 256+sineTable(sineTable < 0);

% print it in hex C code
s = sprintf('char sineTable[%d] = {\n',n);
for i = 1:n-1
  s = [s sprintf('  0x%02X,\n',uint8(sineTableQuantized(i)))];
end
% last one
s = [s sprintf('  0x%02X};\n',uint8(sineTableQuantized(n)))];
fprintf('%s',s);
```